# Replacing all characters that are not digits, commas or dots using regular expression

Tags: java, regex, replace

Here's what I was doing:

```
public static String replaceCharAt(String s, int pos, char c) {
    return s.substring(0, pos) + c + s.substring(pos + 1);
  }

for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
{
    if(str.charAt(i)!=',' || str.charAt(i)!='.' || !Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
         replaceCharAt(str,i,'x');
}
```

but I've been told that regular expressions are way more effective. Unfortunately I don't know how to use regex, I'm just learning for the very first time.

This is the regex I'm using to replace all non-digit characters

```
str.replaceAll("\\D", "")
```

but how can I make dots and commas not being removed?

Comment: `str.replaceAll([\\D\.\,], "");`

Comment: `str.charAt(i) = "";` won't work because you can't assign to the result of a method; nor is the type of `String.charAt` a `String` (it's `char`).

Comment: @ggorlen thanks, fixed!

Comment: @AndyTurner, I overlooked that assignment, thanks!

Comment: "I've been told that regular expressions are way more effective" your code doesn't even compile. You can look at regex, but you would also benefit from understanding why the current code doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) [`[^\d.,]+`](https://regex101.com/r/g6P5YL/1) to match not a digit, dot or a comma one or more times.

In Java:

```
String regex = "[^\\d.,]+";
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/KYMCA83741)

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: How can we modify it to have only two numbers before . dot? ex: 123add.65asdj.43df to 12.65.43